# FFmpeg/libavcodec failing for asv1 conversion using PHPVideoToolkit

Tags: ffmpeg

It seems that I can not get libavcodec running with my install of ffmpeg.  I say 'it seems' because the searching I have done based on the following error message has gotten me to that point:

> PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "`/home/clrock/public_html/drupal-7.14/sites/default/files/img/videos/original/StoryboardMovie.mp4`" was found, but the file contained no data. Please check the available codecs compiled with FFmpeg can support this type of conversion. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from `PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()`.

The ffmpeg command is

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
-i '/home/clrock/public_html/drupal-7.14/sites/default/files/img/videos/original/StoryboardMovie.mp4' \
-strict experimental -vcodec 'asv1' -s '640x480' -acodec 'aac' -ac '2'  \
/tmp/1343067407-500d950fbd290.3gp
```

I can not seem to find out how to get ffmpeg to configure with libavcodec.  It seems all of the necessary files are there in `/usr/src/ffmpeg-0.7.12/libavcodec`.

ffmpeg can make mp4 and flv files fine, only when using asv1 does it hang up.

Comment: So what does `PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()` contain?  If you run `ffmpeg -codecs` from the command line does it list asv1 as an available encoding codec?

Comment: array(5) { ["reading_from_cache"]=> bool(false) ["ffmpeg-found"]=> bool(false) ["compiler"]=> array(0) { } ["binary"]=> array(0) { } ["ffmpeg-php-support"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: The output from getFFmpegInfo() is `array(5) { ["reading_from_cache"]=> bool(false) ["ffmpeg-found"]=> bool(false) ["compiler"]=> array(0) { } ["binary"]=> array(0) { } ["ffmpeg-php-support"]=> bool(false) }`.  `ffmpeg -codecs` is a very long list and asv1 is included

Comment: Ok.  There is something wrong with the codecs I'm choosing, I believe.  I'm focusing on finding presets that I can start from.  I changed a couple encoding options and now I broke mp4 but webm is working.

Comment: Glancing over [the PHPVideoToolkit source](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/source/browse/trunk/phpvideotoolkit/phpvideotoolkit.php5.php), the output you get for `getFFmpegInfo()` looks like a lot less than it should be.  It also looks like `hasCodecSupport` would be another good function to check the output of.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to change the ouput settings. For webm:

```
vcodec=libvpx acodec=vorbis
```

Form Mp4

```
vcodec=libx264 acodec=libmp3lame
```

With Mp4, I couldn't use the libx264-hq preset as something was missing.  I'm not sure what, but it's good to know I don't need it.

Thanks.